# REGEXP not working in QSqluery execution with SQLITE

Tags: regex, database, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I'm trying to do the following:

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQuery *qry = new QSqlQuery(mydb);
QString qstr = "Select * from table WHERE Name REGEXP ";
qstr.append("'");
qstr.append(m_filterText);
qstr.append("'");
qry->prepare(qstr);
qry->exec();
model->setQuery(*qry);
```

It's not returning anything and the following error is recorded:

> No query Unable to fetch row

Any idea on why this is happening? If I run this in `sqlite3` shell, it works. Seems like the `QSQLITE` adapter is missing a `REGEXP` definition. Not sure.

Comment: execute this: `if (qry->lastError().isValid())  qDebug() < qry->lastError().text();` after `qry->exec()`

Comment: that's what I did by calling `qry->lastError().text()` and I got the error above

Comment: Do you print any messages?

Comment: yes I print the message: >No query Unable to fetch row

Comment: try with: `QString qstr = QString("Select * from table WHERE Name REGEXP '%1'").arg(m_filterText);
qry->prepare(qstr);
qry->exec();`

Comment: same error. The query seems fine from what I've seen in debugging it by looking at `qstr`

Comment: You could share your complete or at least reproducible code to test it completely through github, dropbox, drive or similar.

Comment: I was able to get the same result, even faster by using `LIKE '%filter%'` instead of `REGEXP` and there's no error with the use of `LIKE`

Comment: You could share a code where you can do a test and try to help you.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: working on win 10. the code is large and interconnected. I was able to resolve the issue though with my above comment.

Comment: You could create another project that performs the particular task to verify if the code works, in addition to sharing that code.

Comment: **Why are you not using a prepared query? You're asking to be owned by Bobby Tables again** (look it up).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you really should have a talk with Bobby Tables...

Besides that, SQLITE has a `REGEXP` operation defined but it's not implemented by SQLITE. So every framework etc has to do it separately. Unfortunately, Qt does not have it implemented thus your query, once defined right, will not work.

You either have to implement `REGEXP` yourself or wait until Qt 5.10. Then Qt will provide a basic implementation: http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/sql-driver.html#enable-regexp-operator.